# No provider for MockClientService

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have created fake service :

```
@Injectable()
class MockClientService {
 CHAT_URL = '';
 public planOrders = new Subject<PlanOrderModel[]>();
 private subject: Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>;

constructor() {
this.planOrders.next([{
  PlanDirective: 'Create Directive', Physician: 'REMOTE-RO', PlanPriority: 2,
  PlanNotes: '', PlanOrderId: 'Order_1', PatientDetails: { 'ID': '210598', 'Name': 'Ruffin Abdullah', 'AnonymizedID': '' },
  StructureSetID: 'CT_1', MachineID: 'Scanner Test', LastUpdated: '05/12/2018', DueDate: '05/12/2018', Status: '2',
  GatewayID: 0, selected: false, active: true
}]);
```

}
 }

This is my TestBed :

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [FormsModule, TableModule, DialogModule, HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
    { path: 'Orders', component: PlanOrderComponent },
    { path: 'plan-order-history', component: PlanOrderHistoryComponent }
  ])],
  declarations: [HeaderComponent, SubheaderComponent, PlanOrderComponent, FilterPlanOrderPipe,
    PlanOrderHistoryComponent],
  providers: [PlanOrderService, ToastsManager, ToastOptions,
    ConfirmationService, ViewContainerRef, DataServiceService, AppService]
}).overrideComponent(PlanOrderComponent, {
  set: {
    providers: [
      { provide: ClientService, useClass: MockClientService }
    ]
  }
});
```

Even after injecting MockClientService and getting error : 
NullInjectorError: No provider for MockClientService

Comment: You don't need to do the "overrideComponent". Just include your mockClientService into the providers with { provide: ClientService, useClass: MockClientService } and it should work.

Comment: I have tried that too. It is giving same error then also

Comment: Remove @Injectable()

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, there is no need to call `overrideComponent`, you can just provide the mock service in the `providers` array like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ DummyComponent ],
    providers: [{
      provide: ClientService,
      useClass: MockClientService
    }]
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```

> I have made a small stackblitz showing how to mock a service in a unit
>   test
>   [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-cyurjm?file=app%2Fdummy%2Fdummy.component.spec.ts).